# Always pay same price, regardless of tax country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

We've a webshop built in Woocommerce and we accept crypto payments (Bitcoin, ETH etc).

Since we're based in the EU we need to calculate tax on our prices.

So every customer that's inside the EU needs to pay tax.

We've displayed the prices including tax (0.1 BTC for example). The customer pays 0.1 BTC and there is already a 0.02 TAX calculated within that price.

But what if we get a customer from without the EU? We want them to pay 0.1 BTC as well but then without the TAX rate.

Is this possible within woocommerce?

Thanks in advance!

Mand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been searching high and low for a solution to this problem. Actually found it just 5 min ago.

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false' );
```

Read more, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-Taxes-Work-in-WooCommerce#prices-including-tax---experimental-behavior

Comment: You sir, are my hero for today! Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :)