# Disable VAT for specific countries in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Original code makes all prices set to the same, no matter what the VAT % is. So if a item cost 100$ with 25% VAT, it will cost 100$ with 80% VAT or even 0% VAT.

That works fine, however, some countries I would like to remove the VAT for.

Original code from [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042094/always-pay-same-price-regardless-of-tax-country/51045315#51045315):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false' );
```

My code that is not working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 'custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
function custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $vat_countries ) {

// Which countries should it be applide to?
    $countries = array( 'AX', 'AT', 'BE', 'BA', 'HR', 'CZ', 'DK', 'FI', 'GR', 'HU', 'IS', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'NL', 'PO', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'CH', 'GB');

    // Avoiding errors on admin and on other pages
    if( is_admin() || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $countries;

// Remove field $countries
if (($key = array_search($countries, $vat_countries)) !== false) {
    return false;
}
return $vat_countries;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function argument is not related to countries, it's a boolean value (true by default), see that [on `wc_get_price_excluding_tax()` function code.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_excluding_tax.html#991-1029).

You need to get the customer billing country from `WC_Customer` Object (or the shipping country).

So your code should be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 'custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
function custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $boolean ) {
    // Avoiding errors on admin and on other pages
    if( is_admin() || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $boolean;

    // Defined array of countries where the boolean value should be "false"
    $countries = array( 'AX', 'AT', 'BE', 'BA', 'HR', 'CZ', 'DK', 'FI', 'GR', 'HU', 'IS', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'NL', 'PO', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'CH', 'GB');

    // Remove field $countries
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_billing_country(), $countries ) ) {
        $boolean = false;
    }
    return $boolean;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works (untested).

Comment: Make sense, I'll try it. thanks, it's giving me a syntax error on the $boolean = false; row?

Comment: @RomeoPatrick My fault, there was a missing bracket in the if statement… Try it again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Spent a while on the same issue. What bothers me with this approach is that the filter is rather a shop level rule (Do we adjust non-base location prices in this shop?), while the applied criteria is more about a certain customer (Should the customer pay VAT or not?). 
$customer->get_is_vat_exempt() seems more correct for this kind of customization, but it doesn't allow any filtering, and using set_is_vat_exempt() would save the value to the customer, which raises compatibility concerns. I'll go for the solution by @LoicTheAztec for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this a as separate answer although it's mostly based on [@LoicTheAztec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62178988/3963594).

The only difference is that the code checks customers shipping country (not billing country), since [VAT follows the "destination principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_value_added_tax#How_it_works), that is, VAT is calculated based on the country where the product/service is consumed. (the case for EU at least).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 'custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes' );
function custom_eu_vat_number_country_codes( $boolean ) {
    // Avoiding errors on admin and on other pages
    if( is_admin() || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $boolean;

    // Defined array of countries where the boolean value should be "false"
    $countries = array( 'AX', 'AT', 'BE', 'BA', 'HR', 'CZ', 'DK', 'FI', 'GR', 'HU', 'IS', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'NL', 'PO', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'CH', 'GB');

    // Remove field $countries
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $countries ) ) {
        $boolean = false;
    }
    return $boolean;
}
```